# Angular 7 : HOw to hide a modal in ts file?

Tags: angular7

I need to hide a modal after editing form. How to add modal dismiss in ts file. When i have used data dismiss into save button the modal dismiss but the save opreration does not work.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="editExperienceModal" tabindex="-1" 
        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="listing-modal-2 modal-dialog">

            <div class="submit_listing_box">
              <h3>Experience</h3>
              <form #f="ngForm"  class="form-alt" (ngSubmit)=editExperience()>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <label>Intitulé du poste </label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="titre" [(ngModel)]="exp.titre" type="text" #titre="ngModel">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <label> Entreprise </label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="organisation" [(ngModel)]="exp.organisation" #organisation="ngModel"
                      type="text">
                  </div> 
                <div class="vfx-price-btn">
         <button type="submit" class="purchase-btn pull-right">  
              Save</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Change your buttontype from type="submit" to type ="button"
- Call  your function editExperience() and at the same time call
  "dismiss-modal". by doing so you able to dismiss modal and call
  function too. hope this may help you.

**here is example:**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="editExperienceModal" tabindex="-1" 
            role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
              aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="listing-modal-2 modal-dialog">

                <div class="submit_listing_box">
                  <h3>Experience</h3>
                  <form #f="ngForm"  class="form-alt" (ngSubmit)=editExperience()>
                    <div class="row">

                      <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label>Intitulé du poste </label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="titre" [(ngModel)]="exp.titre" type="text" #titre="ngModel">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label> Entreprise </label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="organisation" [(ngModel)]="exp.organisation" #organisation="ngModel"
                          type="text">
                      </div> 
                    <div class="vfx-price-btn">
             <button type="button" (click)="editExperience()"  data-dismiss="editExperienceModal" class="purchase-btn pull-right">  
                  Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: i have changed the button type and added data-dismiss but it is still not working

Comment: there is no errors. the fom's values are updated but the modal is not hide